# How to remove text inside single quotes in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with 80000 lines.
There are file paths in the text that look like,

```
create tablespace ts1 datafile '/u01/app/oracle/abcd.dbf' size 10m;
create tablespace ts2 datafile '/u01/app/oracle/xyz3.dbf' size 10m;
create tablespace ts3 datafile '/u01/app/oracle/jlhk04.dbf' size 10m;
```

Now I want to remove the text inside the single quotes in every line
and replace it with a blank space..

How Can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Press **Ctrl+H** to open the Replace Dialog
   or go over the Menu->Search->Replace.
2. Select Search Mode: **Regular Expression**
3. Use the Regular Expression **'[^']+'**
4. Hit **Replace All**

The Regular Expression **'[^']+'** mean:
Search a string that begins and end with single quote.
**[^']+** Between them one or more characters that ar not signle quote.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Go to Notepad++, open replace (`Ctrl + H`), then select Regular Expression and type the below code.

```
\x27[a-zA-Z0-9/.]{1,}\x27
```

it will match any string like `'/u01/app/oracle/abcd.dbf'` and in replace enter space. this should work.

A reference to Notepad++ RegEx can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.back_references).

Comment: It says 0 occurences replaced